# отображение контента на странице

Tags: android, html, css

Есть такая проблема с с полем ввода input на мобильных устройствах. Когда оно становится активным все элементы выше и ниже него становятся меньше и сдвигаются. 
Это проявляется только при установке css для портрета и пейзажа

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

Если оставить одну css

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="portrait.css">
```

то все нормально. Есть ли способ избежать этого с двумя css?

Comment: Нужно больше информации.. Код, скриншот, ссылка на сайт.. Так быстрее и точнее ответ будет. И так, немножно информации, не "портрета и пейзажа", а "вертикальный и горизонтальный").

Comment: teatr59.ru/mobile/feedback-bad.php заходить с телефона. при активации любого поля ввода верхний баннер уходит вниз